# bundling vs systemjs angular2 asp.net core mvc app - ready for production

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, web-deployment, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to get our angular2 asp.net core app built for production

in dev, currently it is using systemjs to load in all the modules as necessary, but clearly in production this would amount to a ridiculous amount of requests for all the associated libraries etc.

I have been attempting to bundle everything up using browserify (gulp) but this seems to result in an enormous app bundle - using the main.js as the entry point - because of the sheer number of components we have (which is only likely to grow further) 
did think about browserify'ing on a per component basis, but expect it would then bundle all the imported angular modules/rxjs etc for each component too..
doing this would likely also necessitate installing node on our build server which might be hard to get agreed.

is there a recommended way to approach this?
either use bundling or module loading, or some combination of the 2?
essentially the project needs to end up as a nuget package ready for deploy containing the wwwroot folder with all the static assets and dll's 
- such that I do not want to be serving files up from the node_modules folder at all..

hope that makes some sense, any pointer gratefully received

Comment: There is a built-in [route lazy-loading feature](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#lazy-loading-route-config) in angular 2. So you don't have to load the whole application at once.

Comment: I think the problem is that you want bundle everything together and keep the advantages of async loading. This simply doesnt work, either bundle a part and load in async or bundle everything together as one and add a little tree shaking for dead code to reduce the size. you can't automagically have both without some changes in your architecture